# How to copy a Sharepoint page?

Tags: 2010, web-part, development, sharepoint-designer, asp.net

In SPD2010 (Sharepoint Designer 2010) under "Site Pages" I created ASPX page  ASPControls.aspx, added and configured AdRotator ASP.NET control.
Having ollowed "Using ASP.NET Validation Controls" of [O'Reilly's "Microsoft® SharePoint® Designer 2010 Step by Step"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627338.do)

Everything worked.

Now I want to copy aspx page (with another name). I right-click ASPControls.aspx --> choose "Copy" --> navigate to another (created for this) (sub)folder --> Right-click --> Paste.
Further actions to complete copying are optional: rename page --> move it to needed (previous) location

Now when I press F12 to run the copied page, I am getting:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The AdRotator AdRotator1 could not find the AdvertisementFile or the
>   file is invalid.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The AdRotator AdRotator1
>   could not find the AdvertisementFile or the file is invalid

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

When I check the value AdvertisementFile  property in "Tag properties", the value is present and correct.

The same problems after copying other ASPX pages like:

- The ControlToValidate property of 'RequiredFieldValidator1' cannot be blank

while this property is not blank, etc.

Well, the question boils down to:
How can I copy pages created in SPD 2010 or Sharepoint 2010?

I've read a lot about it including [How to copy web part pages?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/how-to-copy-web-part-pages) with references in it, et al but still do not have an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the page into another folder you'll have to make sure any relative file paths for your dependencies resolve properly.  Sounds like your AdRotator cannot find its dependent file for precisely this reason.